# Writing R data.table object to hdf5 file

Tags: r, data.table, rhdf5

I have R data.table which I tried to write as h5 file using rhdf5 package. This gives me a warning `h5writeAttribute.default(Attr[[i]], h5obj, name = names(Attr)[i]) :
  No function found to write attribute of class 'externalptr'. Attribute '.internal.selfref' is not written to hdf5-file.`
When I read the file, I see that many columns are not there. Specifically, columns of type `list()` are missing. I get same results whether I use `write.attributes=TRUE` or `write.attributes=FALSE` in `h5write` function. Any suggestions?
Reproducible Example:

```
library(rhdf5)
library(data.table)

tmp <- data.table(character = "Name", 
              logical = "FALSE",
              list = list(tmp = c("a", "b")),
              logical2 = "TRUE"
)
h5write(tmp, "tmp.h5", "test",write.attributes=TRUE)
h5closeAll()
tmpRead = h5read(file="tmp.h5","test")
h5closeAll()

tmp
character logical list logical2
1   Name    FALSE   c("a", "b") TRUE

tmpRead
character logical logical2
1   Name    FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible so others can help

Comment: @Tung Thanks, I have now added a reproducible example.

Comment: Have you seen this one https://www.neonscience.org/hdf5-intro-r ?

Comment: maybe use data.frame instead of data.table?